# Explanation of Template Matching formula

Tags: derivatives, summation, image-processing

Can someone please explain the formula f.) on [OpenCV template matching](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html)

Formula:

[image: Template Matching Formula CCOEFF and CCOEFF_NORMED]

Suppose template image is 3x4 and source image is 15x20 how would the mathematical operations follow...

Comment: Resample both images to the same resolution (for example 3x4 or 15x20). Otherwise, there is no magic, irrespective of what implementation, etc., you're using.