# Explaining template matching algorithm's formula (opencv2)

Tags: image-processing

I am struggling to understand [OpenCv's formula](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html#which-are-the-matching-methods-available-in-opencv) for the **CV_TM_CCOEFF** template matching algorithm

[image]

Where

[image]

Specifically, in `R(x,y)`, what do the `x'` and `y'`'s mean? I dont imagine they are derivatives, because the values are all integers so its derivative wrt anything would be 0. Then `x + 0 = x`.

Secondly, what is `T'(x',y')`?

I found [the other](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1622559/explanation-of-template-matching-formula) topic asking a question exactly on this but the answer is very vague and unhelpful. Thanks

Edit:

After further reading, apparently `T(x', y')` is the image pixel value for a pixel `(x,y)` in the template image and `I(x+x', y+y')` is the image pixel value for the corresponding pixel position in the target image. With that in mind, what is `T(x'',y'')` and `I(x+x'', y+y'')`?

Answer (score 1):

`x'` and `x''` are just variables distinct from `x`. It's awkward notation, yes.

`T'` is a normalized version of `T`, where the mean of `T` is subtracted. Likewise for `I'` (though this one is not used anywhere? I think the equation for `R` should use `I'` rather than `I`).

Then, `R` is the convolution of the image `I` with the normalized *and mirrored* `T` (cross-correlation is the same as convolution, but without the mirroring of the kernel, note how it uses `x+x'` rather than `x-x'` as you would see in a convolution).